# LinqExpression: How do I get the value from comparison evaluation

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

I am trying to translate a LinqExpression into a sql statement.  For example, on my Repository base class I have a method Find that accepts a LinqExpression as its argument.  Within the Find method, I am calling a method that performs the following action:

```
var equality = expression as BinaryExpression;
                return equality.Left.Translate() + " = " +
                       equality.Right.Translate();
```

How can I get the value of the variable on the right side and not just the variable name, currently I am only getting the variable name.  ex. Find(x => x.ID = variable);  if variable is currently set to 7 I need a way to get the value 7 and not the name variable.  What would be the correct way to get to the value stored in the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Matt Warren's article *LINQ: Building an IQueryable Provider - Part III*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx). It contains code for `Evaluator` class which will inline all values that can be inlined. In your case, it will replace `variable` with a `ConstantExpression` that contains the value 7.

The rest of the articles in the series might be of interest to you too.

Comment: Trying to locally evaluate the expression before using _Expression.Compile()_ like discussed in the cited article is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting into [MemberExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx) or [ConstantExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression.aspx) respectively:

```
  var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Left;
  var constantExpression = (ConstantExpression) expression.Right;
```

Oh, missed it was a variable. Then the right operand should be of type *ParameterException*. However, to get its value you may use

```
 Func<object> getValue = expression.Compile();
 var value = getValue();
```

Note that this may be slow.

Comment: Except in this case, `expression.Right` seems to be captured closure variable, not a constant. That means it won't be `ConstantExpression`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed it was a variable. So it should be a _ParameterExpression_.